# How to mock classes in Rails controller with mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocking, mocha.js

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use mocha mocking library for certain type of unit tests in Rails.

I have a controller, which initializes an object from a helper library, and then calls a function on it. My code looks similar to

```
class ObjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_adapter

  def index
    response = @adapter.get_objects

    render json: response
  end

  private
    def set_adapter
      arg = request.headers["X-ARG"]
      @adapter = Adapter::Adapter.new(arg)
    end
end
```

In my tests, I want mock the adapter to make sure that the get_objects() method is called. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to implement this kind of tests, but I seem to be stuck on getting the idea on how to mock an existing object within a class.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stub it like this:

```
adapters = mock('object')
adapters.expects(:get_objects)
Adapter::Adapter.expects(:new).with('<X-ARG-HEADER-HERE>').returns(adapters)
# Run rest of test here to trigger calling the index method
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems to be working, but I wonder what does the 'object' in the mock function call mean?

Comment: It means that you're just mocking a generic ruby base object. You could mock any class this way.